# How to find an exact word in a string in Access? For example the word Intro in part of a course name?

Tags: ms-access

For example; Intro to Computers
Find all courses with the word Intro

I need to find all the Introductory courses; so will also be looking for Introductory.  I know how to use the wildcard to find them; but what if there are other words that start with Intro?

Comment: Then you will get those records as well. That's the nature of pattern matching. I know this is stating the obvious but not really anything else can be said considering the broad scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could assume that the word *Introduction* will only ever be shortened to *Intro* and hence use a selection criteria of:

```
LIKE "Introduct*" OR LIKE "Intro *"
```

This will therefore match all titles starting with:

- Intro ...
- Introduction...
- Introductory...

Answer (score 0):

You could use four criteria combined with "Or":

- Like "Intrduct*"
- Like "Intro *"
- Like "* Introduct*"
- Like "* Intro *"